# Add a number column below other number column

Tags: r, rstudio

I can´t join two columns to only one column using cbind or rbind.

I´ve a matrix "m" and values "v", I used c() for transform m and v to columns, and then, used rbind() and cbind(), but it don´t work.

```
> m<-matrix(c(1.3,1.6,2.1,1.8,1.7,2.4),2,3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.3  2.1  1.7
[2,]  1.6  1.8  2.4

> v<-c(3.4, 5.5)
> v
[1] 3.4 5.5
```

Then I tried to create one column with "m" and "v" (with "v" values to the end), using this code:

```
> print(c(m))

[1] 1.3 1.6 2.1 1.8 1.7 2.4

> print(c(v))

[1] 3.4 5.5

> print(cbind(c(m),c(v)))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.3  3.4
[2,]  1.6  5.5
[3,]  2.1  3.4
[4,]  1.8  5.5
[5,]  1.7  3.4
[6,]  2.4  5.5

> print(rbind(c(m),c(v)))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]  1.3  1.6  2.1  1.8  1.7  2.4
[2,]  3.4  5.5  3.4  5.5  3.4  5.5
```

I need a column like this:

```
[1] 1.3 1.6 2.1 1.8 1.7 2.4
[7] 3.4 5.5
```

How can I solve this?
best regards.

Comment: What's wrong with `cbind(m, v)`?

Comment: @r2evans did you mean `c(m, v)`?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. The OP asks about adding columns or such, and then shows a vector, so I just guessed. Perhaps wrongly :-)

Comment: @r2evans : cbind (m, v) create a matrix with other extra column, but I needed the values ​​in a column (or vector). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read in `?c`:

> [`c()`] combines its arguments to form a vector.

So, since `c(m)` coerces the matrix into a vector, you could simply do

```
c(m, v)
# [1] 1.3 1.6 2.1 1.8 1.7 2.4 3.4 5.5
```